# Paypal recurring payments not getting charged

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am using the PayPal REST API in the sandbox. I have set a recurring payment from my customer account to my business account yesterday. Everything was successful, the setup fee was charged. The next payment is due today, at 8 am. 3 Hours have now passed and the payment did not go through.

Even if I request the agreement details now, I have `"next_billing_date": "2018-11-06T08:00:00Z",` (my timezone is GMT, this is not a timezone issue), with `"cycles_completed": "0"`.

I was unable to find mention anywhere of any possible delay. Is there an issue with my setup, or is the time bit of the date just for the sake of being ISO 8601 and the charges happen sometime on the specified day ?

Answer (score 0):

The payment will actually get charged within 24 hours. Had 3 payments with "next_billing_date": "2018-11-06T10:00:00Z" and all came in in a random order at random times throughout the day.